# Springboot Entity manager cannot reliably process 'persist' call

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

On trying to add to database I get the following
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for the current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call

I have viewed the other answers but none of them solves my issue. What am I failing to understand here or what am I doing wrong?

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
@Transactional
public class TickerRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void save(TickerMessage message) {
        entityManager.persist(message);
    }
}

IN CONFIG:

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbSettings.getDriverClass());
        dataSource.setUrl(dbSettings.getUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(dbSettings.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(dbSettings.getPassword());
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1 from dual");
        dataSource.setLogValidationErrors(true);
        dataSource.setJmxEnabled(true);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(dbSettings.getMaxActive());
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(dbSettings.getMaxIdle());
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "EntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.canaldigital.tsi.csrportal.domain",
                "com.canaldigital.tsi.csrportal.adapter" });
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("EntityManager"); // Important !!
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show-sql", true);
        em.afterPropertiesSet();
        return em;
    }
```

I expect the entry to be saved in the table but I get the following exception Caused by javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for the current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the `EntityManager` with a `TransactionManager`:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
  JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
  txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager().getObject());
  return manager;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot man. Really appreciate it. This worked. I also had to add @EnableTransactionManagement on top of my class though.